# (Android) Room database migration doesn't change database

Tags: android, database-migration, android-room

I need to update the `SQLite-Database` so I created a migration.
While debugging this migration step-by-step, there's no error, but as I see, only the 'journal file is updated.
The change is never committed to the database and I don't really understand what I did wrong so maybe someone can give a advice.?

I have a table called 'image' and I need to create a table called 'attachment'. After that, I need to move all data from 'image' to 'attachment', handle/transform some data and finally delete table 'image'.

**Here's my implementation:**

**1. I added the library to my project**

```
    implementation android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0
    implementation android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0
```

**2. create migration**

```
    val MIGRATION_2_3: Migration = object : Migration(2, 3) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {

    // create table 'attachment'
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE attachment (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, extenal_id INTEGER NOT NULL, userId TEXT, createdDateTime TEXT, displayFileName TEXT, fileExtension TEXT NOT NULL, noData INTEGER, identifier TEXT, commentText TEXT, localBaseFileName TEXT, dirty INTEGER NOT NULL, task_id TEXT NOT NULL, attachmentType INTEGER NOT NULL)")

    // migrate data from table 'image' to 'attachment'
    val cursor = database.query("SELECT * FROM image")
    cursor.moveToFirst()
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {

        // get stored values
        val image_id = cursor.getInt(0)
        val externalId = cursor.getLong(1)
        val customIdentifier = cursor.getString(2)
        val createdAt = cursor.getString(3)
        val imageType = cursor.getString(4)
        val commentText = cursor.getString(5)
        val createdBy = cursor.getString(6)
        // cursor.getString(7)/ / not used anymore
        val imageName = cursor.getString(8)
        val dirty = cursor.getInt(9)
        val task_id = cursor.getString(10)
        // cursor.getString(11) // not used anymore 

        // create migration only for availably images
        if (!imageName.isNullOrEmpty()) {

            // get file extension or 'unknown' if not known
            val fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(imageType) ?: "unknown"

            val contentValues = ContentValues()
            contentValues.put("id", image_id)
            contentValues.put("external_id", externalId)
            contentValues.put("userId", createdBy)
            contentValues.put("createdDateTime", createdAt)
            contentValues.put("displayFileName", imageName)
            contentValues.put"fileExtension", fileExtension)
            contentValues.put"noData", false)
            contentValues.put("identifier", customIdentifier)
            contentValues.put("commentText", commentText)
            contentValues.put("localBaseFileName", imageName.split("_")[0])
            contentValues.put("dirty", dirty)
            contentValues.put("task_id", task_id)
            contentValues.put("attachmentType", DatabaseManager.ATTACHMENT_TYPE_IMAGE)

            // insert new data
            database.insert("attachment", SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE, contentValues)
        }

        // load next entry
        cursor.moveToNext()
    }
    cursor.close()

    // delete old table 'image'
    // database.execSQL("DROP TABLE image")



}
```

}

**3. Added the migration to my Database-Implementation**

```
     Room
            .databaseBuilder(context, Database::class.java, "my_db.db")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
            .build()
```

When I run the code the migration is called without any error. But after migration, only the 'journal'-file is updated, not the database itself!?

Am I something missing here? I don't get it.....  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame on me...

So, here's my solution or what went wrong ;)

I always debugged through the migration process an killed the process after migration has been done....with the result described above.

At least I only had to go one step further to see, that there was a different implementation on my Entity-class for Attachment and the SQL-Statement for create the table during migration...

The field 'id' has been created with the properties:

> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL

while this attribute at the Entity is nullable!

So, what I learned is:
Now I understand that the migration doesn't throw a exception because the creation of the table is correct and the error appears during new initial loading process because only then the difference could be detected.

I don't understand why the journal is not merged directly to the database after migration but OK, that's just one more weired thing on Android ;)

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: I'm in sort of the same situation, but I have no idea what this answer is talking about.